# A unique 6 Digit number using GUID

Tags: guid

Is it possible to create a unique 6 digit number using guid?

I seem to be able to only get 10 digits using :

```
        byte[] buffer = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 6).ToString());
```

Comment: Why do you need to use a guid? If you need six digits, just generate six digits.

Comment: the digits need to be unique everytime, and I dont want to iterate through a list to check the number doesnt exist, it will use a lot of resources.

Comment: GUIDs are "unique enough" because of their length. There's **no** guarantee that truncating a GUID down from 128 bits to a 6 digit number will retain the uniqueness property (in fact, obviously, if you do this at least 1000001 times, you *must* have generated a collision)

Answer (score 0):

GUIDs are not guaranteed to be unique. However, the range from which they are picked up is so large that there indeed is a very low probability of collision.  This is not the case for a six digit number unless you pick each number sequentially or use any other scheme that ensure there is no collision.

EDIT
See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem for the probability of a collision.